# Bootstrap 4.1 in angular 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

How to properly install bootstrap 4 from angular cli in order for all bootstrap components to work?

I was use the following commands:

- npm install --save jquery
- npm install --save popper.js
- npm install --save bootstrap

and config the following in **angular-cli.json** file:

```
   "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

The popover and tooltips doesn't works.. but the bootstrap css is working!

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). It works better with Angular than the jQuery version of the code.

Comment: open browser console is there any errors .

Comment: @mohamedvall no error is displayed!

Comment: @AlejoDev Try to include bootstrap.js instead of bootstrap.min.js file .

Comment: @mohamedvall  I tried it and it does not work

Comment: @AlejoDev by the way yes you installed all what bootstrap required .

Comment: @mohamedvall Yes, in fact locate the packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168956/discussion-between-mohamedvall-and-alejodev).

Answer (score 1):

[Tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) are opt-in for performance reasons, so you need to call it for the elements:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

This will only set tooltips on the elements present *when the call is made* however.  So if you just call this when your app loads, the elements in all your components don't exist yet.  I think you would need to call it in  `NgAfterViewInit`, and you would probably need a ViewChild for the element.

A better way would be to create a directive that would call it on any component the directive is placed on ([*stackblitz link*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhzy2y?file=app%2Fapp.component.html))...

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

// https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
  constructor(er: ElementRef) {
    $(er.nativeElement).tooltip();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" appTooltip>
  This button has a tooltip
</button>
```

Comment: Excuse me please, I'm new in angular, I didn't understand your answer, as what you say in code would be translated. Could you give me an example in code? Thanks!